# import RSA keyPair to KeyStore

Tags: android, certificate, rsa, keystore

For my specific situation, I have to generate a RSA key pair (in my Android application) using the following codes :-

```
 KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
 generator.initialize(1024,new SecureRandom());
 KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair);
```

How can I import the keyPair into the Android keyStore ? I have been searching on the Internet for sometimes and did not get how can I create the self-signed certificate for the RSA public key for import to the keystone.

Appreciate any hints or even sample code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming, you explicitly need to generate keys outside of the `AndroidKeyStore` and import them into the `AndroidKeyStore`. In Android, recommended way to generate keys is generating keys into the `AndroidKeyStore`.

Importing keys to the `AndroidKeyStore` is quite easy. But the tricky part is generating self-signed certificate because there is no built-in X509Certificate generator neither in Android SDK nor in Java itself.

You can generate and import keys with this code snippet:

```java
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
generator.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();

Certificate selfSignedCertificate = generateSelfSignedCertificate(keyPair);
Certificate[] certificateChain = new Certificate[]{selfSignedCertificate};

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
keyStore.load(null);
keyStore.setKeyEntry("meaningful_key_alias", keyPair.getPrivate(), null, certificateChain);
```

**Tricky part, generating X509Certificate:**

Because of there is no provided way to generate `X509Certificate` in an Android, I think the best way to generate certificate is using some trustworthy crypto libraries. `BouncyCastle` is one of the famous one and `bouncycastle-bcpkix` supports certificate generation.

Add dependency in your app's `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.64' // check for updated version
```

implement `generateSelfSignedCertificate` method for your requirement something like:

```java
private X509Certificate generateSelfSignedCertificate(KeyPair keyPair) throws IOException, OperatorCreationException, CertificateException {
    AlgorithmIdentifier sigAlgId = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find("SHA256withRSA"); // don't use SHA1withRSA. It's not secure anymore.
    AlgorithmIdentifier digAlgId = new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find(sigAlgId);
    AsymmetricKeyParameter keyParam = PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
    SubjectPublicKeyInfo spki = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded());
    ContentSigner signer = new BcRSAContentSignerBuilder(sigAlgId, digAlgId).build(keyParam);
    X500Name issuer = new X500Name("CN=Tolga Okur CA, L=Istanbul");
    X500Name subject = new X500Name("CN=MyBeautifulApp, L=Istanbul");
    BigInteger serial = BigInteger.valueOf(1); // Update with unique one if it will be used to identify this certificate
    Calendar notBefore = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar notAfter = Calendar.getInstance();
    notAfter.add(Calendar.YEAR, 20); // This certificate is valid for 20 years.

    X509v3CertificateBuilder v3CertGen = new X509v3CertificateBuilder(issuer,
            serial,
            notBefore.getTime(),
            notAfter.getTime(),
            subject,
            spki);
    X509CertificateHolder certificateHolder = v3CertGen.build(signer);

    return new JcaX509CertificateConverter().getCertificate(certificateHolder);
}
```

**Alternatives:**

If you will generate keys on the server and want to import them securely into the hardware backed keystore, prior to Android 9 (API level 28) and higher which shipped with Keymaster 4 or higher, you can import keys using [WrappedKeyEntry](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/WrappedKeyEntry.html)

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#ImportingEncryptedKeys

Comment: But in your `generateSelfSignedCertificate`, the function `keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded()` will always return null, because user is not allowed to access the private key. Then how does this function work?